# When to use a different package?

Tags: java

I want to get into creating applications, however, I do not know when I should use packages. How should packages be used? How do you know what class to put in what package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for really trivial programs that involve not more than one file, you should always use packages.  A typical package structure is the following

```
com.<your_company>.<your_project>.<sub_system>....
```

or

```
org.<your_organization>.<your_project>.<sub_system>....
```

or (if you don't really belong to any organizations or companies)

```
<some_name>.<your_project>.<sub_system>....
```

where `...` above indicate some more structure within your sub system.  And 
`<some_name>` is just some name that won't be easily in conflict with names that are used by other people.  Don't worry.  Even if you pick a name that
is already used by someone else, you won't be in trouble until the moment you
try to compile two packages of the same name together (obviously that 
should not be allowed).  So these names are all valid choices for `<some_name>`

```
playground
mytest
chapter1
tutorial
```

By convention, package names are always in lowercase.  And in contrast, class names always start with an uppercase character.  For example, in

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
```

the package name is `com.google.gwt.core.client`, and the classname is `EntryPoint`

A good way to learn is to see how other projects organize their packages and classes.  Below I show some examples (which include both package names and class names):

```
org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT;

com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location;
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
com.smartgwt.client.util.DateUtil;
com.smartgwt.client.util.SC;
com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Canvas;
com.smartgwt.client.widgets.HTMLFlow;
com.smartgwt.client.widgets.layout.VLayout;
```

One more observation I would like to make is that package names
are often organized top-down (from big to small).  This convention is 
the reverse of the
convention of how Internet domain names are formed (from small to big).

In the above example, Google's `GWT` project has named their package as

```
com.google.gwt....
```

while Google's Internet domain names are in this form

```
....google.com
```

Many companies and organizations use the reverse of their domain names to form the prefix of their packages.

Comment: This is a silly question, however, what if you don't belong to an organization or company? What would you name your package?

Comment: It should be what you think is logical as per the nature of problem you are trying to solve or contents / classes in your package

Comment: @L4undry -- That is a valid question.  I updated my answer to address your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use packages to seperate classes in your applications by concerns. This helps you in several ways:

- avoid name conflicts between unrelated classes
- group related classes together and isolate unrelated classes in different packages

which all should lead to a better maintainability of your application. If you can find reasonable names for your packages, you can get even a clue what purpose the classes in your package have.

You can read more about it [in the official java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html). A very common use case is to seperate

- application logic (also called `model`) from
- presentation / gui code (often called `view`)

See how Java itself uses packages to seperate things:

- `java.lang.Math` for computations
- `javax.swing`, `java.awt` for gui frameworks
- `java.nio` for buffered input/output

Answer (score 0):

Packages are used in Java in order to prevent naming conflicts, to control access, to make searching/locating and usage of classes, interfaces, enumerations and annotations easier, etc.

If your program has a small amount of classes, like 3 classes
you may not have to separate them into packages.

Your classes are separated into packages in a logical way.

for example:

If you have a program that encryptes data, each of the encryption algorithms
can be separated into classes, and all of those encryption classes can be in the same package